# Application suddenly won't load Bitmap

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, heap-memory

I'm working on a game for android that is near completion, but within the last week suddenly the loading of Bitmap assets used in the game are throwing memory errors.

The main Bitmap in particular that it's throwing errors on is 237kb and 1792X1024 (32 bit).  It is a sprite sheet for a player which is why it is so large, the strange thing is it used to load in and I can actually load in a image that's the map of the game that is 400X800 32bit file that's 413KB without any problems (that isn't a typo, the smaller resolution/same bit file appears larger.  I'm not completely sure why but I'm assuming it has something to do with the colors involved or the fact the sprite sheet is predominantly transparent).  All images were created in GIMP.

I'm unsure what started the errors as there was no change to anything in the code except for an update of the android API (though it would randomly give errors before in early testing).  I have also tried loading in only this spritesheet by itself in a new project which it throws errors, but not on the other larger file.

To make things even more strange, I have a backed up APK from a test phone from when the game didn't throw errors that I've even tried decoding out the png spritesheet and using this exact image (and it still throws errors).  The only way for it to not throw errors is to increase the VM max heap to above 24MB (the default, the smallest I've tried is 48MB and this worked but it's loading a lot slower than it used to).

Is this a possible manifest problem or did something in the SDK change that I'm not aware of?  I've been trying to solve this for several days trying different methods I've found on numerous boards including setting the sample size with `Bitmap.options`, manifest adjustments, changing it on resize, `System.gc()`, `recycle()`, etc.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: The important size for bitmaps isn't the compressed size (which you state here) but the size in memory for the uncompressed bitmap, which is going to be nearly 8 MB for a 1792x1024 bitmap and only 1.3 MB for your 400x800 bitmap.

Comment: Please show of your LogCat output.

Comment: You say you still have the old APK-- does that run correctly on the new Android API or does it now throw errors as well?

Comment: Strangely enough, yes the old one still works when I adb install it after uninstalling the new one.  One more thing to note is that the size of the new one when I increase the memory looks like the screen has doubled in size (in other words the game/layout is drawn smaller than it was before, not filling the screen).  Could there have been something changed in the manafest that may have caused this?

Comment: The log cat and doing memory analysis/debug essentially tells me the spritesheet is the issue (I'm going to reduce the size to fix it unless someone can tell me of a manifest change that will fix it as-is).  Copied below:


08-23 13:27:27.191: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(266): 16515072-byte external allocation too large for this process.
08-23 13:27:27.191: ERROR/(266): VM won't let us allocate 16515072 bytes
08-23 13:27:27.191: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(266): Shutting down VM
08-23 13:27:27.191: WARN/dalvikvm(266): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
etc.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your actual in-memory bitmap is really 237KB. I'm guessing you have a PNG that's 237KB, but the decoded bitmap is much larger in memory. PNG uses a form of lossless compression. As to why it worked before but not now I'm not sure, but I'm not in the least surprised that you're running out of memory with bitmaps that big.

You can use a tool to compact/generate your sprite sheet. Something like this might be useful:

http://spritesheetpacker.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes, it's a png not a bitmap, it's a bitmap object is what I was meaning.  I think I'm going to end up reducing the size by adjusting the POV of the camera on the animation and just rotating the sprite sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an OutOfMemory error then I had the same problem and fixed it as follows. I truly think it is a bug in the native Bitmap code.

Here is what I did: Don't use `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` or `BitmapFactory.decodeFile`. Instead use `BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor`

If that works for you, please let me know as it will help confirm if there is really a bug in the other methods.

Comment: I'm actually using BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image), is there a corresponding overloaded method to pull in from the R.java file?

Comment: I think you can do something like resources.openRawResourceFD(R.drawable.image).getFileDescriptor()

Comment: I ended up just reducing the size of the bitmap by making one directional sprites and rotating them (with some tweaking for alignments).  This took out the 3d effect somewhat but it should be fine in this instance.  Still unsure why this suddenly started throwing errors, but I was planing on reducing the image sizes eventually anyway in the optimization phase.